# R Shiny reactive programming: observe versus observeEvent

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, reactive

I am currently creating a Shiny app in R.  I have reached the point where I putting more advanced reactive programming into my code.  At this point, I am trying to understand how to use the observe function within the reactive context.  However, I also encounter another reactive function call observeEvent.  What is the difference between observe and obsereEvent in R Shiny?

Answer (score 1):

`observe` will trigger anytime there is a reactive dependency inside it, if it's an `input`, `reactiveValues`, `reactiveVal` and so on. The `observeEvent` and `eventReactive` will only trigger upon a change that is within the scope of the trigger. Therefore, `observeEvent` is more conservative than the `observe`. Moreover, you might have memory leaks if you use `observe` incorrectly without flushing or rendering the variables inside it. Personally I almost always use `observeEvent`

Comment: Thanks!  This is helpful.  I get it now.